# How to use the screen manager without .kv file

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have tried to create the multiple screen(i.e tried to use Screen manager) without the use of .kv file i.e all in .py file.But i am unable to create it . please help me out . Basically I want to know how to use screen manager without. Kv file

I had tried to make it but i am unable to do that

```
# kivy code 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class SwitchApp(App): 

    # define build function 
    def build(self): 

        # Create the manager
        sm = ScreenManager()

        # Add few screens
        for i in range(4):
            screen = Screen(name='Title %d' % i)
            sm.add_widget(screen)

        # By default, the first screen added into the ScreenManager will be
        # displayed. You can then change to another screen.

        # Let's display the screen named 'Title 2'
        # A transition will automatically be used.
        sm.current = 'Title 2'

        return sm


# Run the kivy app 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
     SwitchApp().run()
```

Comment: Your code is correct, just that as the Screen are empty you can not tell the difference, to differentiate add a Label to each Screen: `screen.add_widget(Label(text="%d" % i))` after `sm.add_widget(screen)`, do not forget to import Label: `from kivy.uix.label import Label`

Comment: but still the screen is not switching to another

Comment: With your code plus the changes that I indicate works correctly for me.

Comment: Can u please give the corrected code may be i am doing  some mistake and if possible please tell me now how can i add button in it may be i am doing  some mistake

Comment: Thanks but still the screen 2 is the output i want to move from 2 to 3 which is not happning in it

Comment: You should clearly indicate that it is *How to use the screen manager*, since that phrase is very broad. It could be like you point to change the screens with buttons or any other element, or maybe reverse the order of the screens, or do not know what else. Be precise if you want help. Read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: I am extremely sorry now can you please help me

Comment: Edit your question to place the precise information, maybe if you do it then someone will help you, bye.

Answer (score 0):

i added the widget for each screen

(screen.add_widget(Label(text="%d" % i)))

and i selected the screen 1 to be presented, you can switch between them

```
    sm.current = 'Title 1'
```

## kivy code

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.label import Label

class SwitchApp(App):

```
# define build function

def build(self):

    # Create the manager

    sm = ScreenManager()

    # Add few screens

    for i in range(4):

        screen = Screen(name='Title %d' % i)

        screen.add_widget(Label(text="%d" % i))

        sm.add_widget(screen)




    sm.current = 'Title 1'

    return sm
```

## Run the kivy app

if **name** == '**main**':

```
 SwitchApp().run()
```